# How to skip repeated data using php and mysqli

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I want to remove duplicated data in the row.

Please see the table :[image: Table 1]

My code below:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$password = "pass";
$database = "test4";
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("Connection Error");

$query = "SELECT * FROM sample";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query);
$field_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: $database </h1>";
echo " <table border='1' width='50%'><tr> ";
// printing table headers
for ($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++){
$field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
echo "<td><b>{$field->name}</b></td> ";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
echo "<tr>";
// $row is array... foreach(..)put every element
// of $row to $cell variable
 foreach ($row as $cell){
 echo " <td>$cell</td> ";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

What i want is the result show as [image: table-2].

- Duplicated "date" and "transac" to be removed.

Hope you all can provide me a better solution~!
Thanks a lot~!

Comment: Save the values of `date` and `transac` in variables. If the value in the current row is the same as the variable, output a blank cell instead of the value from the row.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get same value repeatedly then you have to use `DISTINCT` in your query. So your query should be

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE, TRANSAC FROM table_name";
```

When the query will execute then it won't retrieve the same value twice for DATE & TRANSAC field. 
Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Don't think that's what he's after. He wants to visually dedupe it by displaying a blank cell.